# Copy/paste a range as values in VBA, instead of the entire sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Right now I am doing this:

```
xlwb.Sheets(curSheet).Cells.Copy
xlwb.Sheets(curSheet).Cells.PasteSpecial (xlValues)
```

This lets me copy/paste the entire sheet in-place as-values.

However I technically only want to do this for all columns between row 1 and some row near the bottom, call it `finalRow`. There is some content after that I wish to leave as formulas.

How can I copy/paste the rows from 1 to `finalRow` as-value? I'm technically running this code from Access VBA but this code is for Excel.

Comment: What column are you trying to copy `the rows from 1 to finalRow as-value`?

Comment: @Kyle All columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following syntax

```
xlwb.Worksheets(curSheet).Rows(1 & ":" & lastRow).Copy
xlwb.Worksheets(curSheet).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Change the paste range as required.

Comment: This appears to work... is there a way to lose the selection lines that appear afterward? They didn't appear to with the old code

Comment: Do you mean marching ants?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. The moving dotted-lines around the copied range. I have `xlwb.Sheets(curSheet).Cells(1, 1).Select` already but that doesn't seem to remove the ants.

Comment: Use Application.CutCopyMode = False

Comment: Glad it helped. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Skip the clipboard when copying only values:

```
With xlwb.Sheets(curSheet).Rows("1:" & lastrow)
    .Value = .Value
End With
```